# MySQL Slow query after approx 12000 rows returned

Tags: mysql

I've got a table which is:
power_ref INT primary key
watts INT
time DATETIME

It's got a few million rows, it's basically the current power consumption of my house every six seconds.

To generate a graph of a day's entries, I have the following query (slightly modified as I really replace the manually entered date with now()):

"select watts as Watts, time as Time from power where date(time)=date('2015-07-10') order by time desc limit 14400;"

There is an index on the "time" column, but this query ignores it. It takes about 15seconds to run.

However, if I issue the following:

"select watts as watts, time as time from power where date(time)=date('2015-07-10') order by time desc limit 12000;"

The query completes in about 0.1sec, and MySQL uses the index on the time column.

I've tried the following (to force use of the index, but MySQL still won't use the index)

"select watts, time from power USE INDEX (timeIndex) where date(time)=date('2015-07-10') order by time desc limit 14400;"

I find if the index is used by issuing "explain" in front of the query.

I've put the limit of 14400 as this is the max amount of entries in a day, not really needed, but just in case.

Comment: Add the explain for the two queries: 14400 and 12000 limit, it may be of some help to understand the problem.

Comment: It wont use the index since it needs to apply the date() function to EACH ROW. Try doing the same query but without aplying the date function to the column, and instead adding the time to the comparison value, in the correct YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s format and again, withh no date function as its not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer determined that a full table scan would be quicker. This behaviour changes once the data volume changes. USE INDEX is not forcing the index, it is forcing mysql to disregard other indexes. FORCE INDEX will force the use of the index:

```
select watts, time from power FORCE INDEX (timeIndex) 
where date(time)=date('2015-07-10') order by time desc limit 14400;
```

Should get you your wanted index behaviour

Comment: This does give me the index behavior - it also seems to shed light on why MySQL was not using the index - When I run the query now it executes in ~0.3sec, however the first time it's run, the fetch takes over a minute. There is seemingly a cache problem - any ideas?

Comment: The fetch: Can you clarify that one? If the query runs 0.3s, that should include the time of fetching the records. THe output to a display of 14k records can take a while. I usually benchmark queries by either putting the data in a temporary table or by adding a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (the original query) a; as to force the fetching of all records

Comment: I've been issuing the query in MySQL workbench and it specifies two times - one for the query duration and one for the fetch. My guess is that there is some sort of cache size problem, but I'm out of my depth...

Comment: The fetch is just copying the records from server to client. That is only influenced by network and/or cpu processing power of the client: It can be optimized by retrieving only the data you use. Most of the time it can be ignored for further optimization.